# Is there a method that gets called on app uninstallation?

Tags: ios, uikit, uninstallation

I have a very specific need to handle some cases if my iOS app gets uninstalled. But I cannot find any method so far that gets called in case the app gets uninstalled. I have searched around with similar questions but cannot find anything usefull. Can anyone suggest something please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible.
But you can check if the application has re-installed by storing a key in iCloud using keychain.